# How to categorize "grrrr", "errhh", "argh",..?

Tags: terminology, parts-of-speech

1. What are these called in English?
2. Are they same thing as "Gosh" or "Gee"?
3. Maybe sounds of emotional changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are called [*interjections*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection).

> In grammar, an *interjection* or *exclamation* is a lexical category used to express an isolated emotion or sentiment on the part of the speaker [...]. Filled pauses such as *uh*, *er*, *um*, are also considered interjections. Interjections are typically placed at the beginning of a sentence.

[*Gosh*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gosh#Interjection) and [*gee*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gee#Interjection) are interjections, too.

Comment: +1 - Just for the record, they are also called Discourse Fillers (or maybe just _Fillers_ I'm not sure now, but anyway, note that they are different from the Discourse Markers).

Answer (score 1):

"Grrrr" and "argh" are onomatopea, at least accoridng to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia (notice the extra i)

Comment: Er ... no, they're not. They are neither onomatopoeic, nor mentioned in that WP article.